# Detect if destination is a Uniswap V3 Pool

Tags: uniswap

Is there a way for a contract to check a destination address to see if it's a Uniswap V3 pool?

Comment: One dummy way is to check if it implements the interface - check that each function exists (unsure even how that should be done)

Comment: Problam is, anyone can do that. It seems like there ought to be a way to prove that it is legit but the deployer doesn't seem to record what it does apart from the event log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All valid Uniswap V3 pools must implement the view functions [`token0` and `token1`](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolImmutables.sol#L13).

Call those functions on the address in question, and use the addresses returned by those functions to call [`getPool`](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol#L48) on the canonical `UniswapV3Factory`. The address returned by `UniswapV3Factory.getPool` should match the address of the contract in question. If not, you can be sure that the contract address was NOT deployed using the canonical `UniswapV3Factory` and thus is not a valid pool.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest implementation would be to simply check for the destination contract's factory parameter, since the single common denominator of all Uniswap V3 pools is that they all have the same Uniswap V3 factory address as follows:

```
assert(UniswapV3Pool(destination).factory == 0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984);
```

But then, anyone would be able to deploy a mock contract containing that data. Just like anyone would be able to deploy a contract that implements the Uniswap V3 pair interface.

Comment: I'm struggling with a way to be sure because there will be an incentive to mimic it.

Comment: @RobHitchens all the Uniswap V3 pools also share the same contract creator address, which is that Uniswap V3 factory mentioned above. Sadly, there is no way to check with certainty for any contract's creator address in Solidity.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to recompute the theoretical pool address (since it's deterministic, but not the same as in V2) and compare to the observed address.

In solidity:

```
function isUniswapPoolAddress(
    address token0,
    address token1,
    uint24 fee,
    address is_this_a_pool
    ) external returns (bool) {

    bytes POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH = '0xe34f199b19b2b4f47f68442619d555527d244f78a3297ea89325f843f87b8b54';
        
    address theo_adr;
   
    bytes32 pubKey = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(hex'ff', address(factory_address), keccak256(abi.encode(token0, token1, fee)), POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH));

    //bytes32 to address:
    assembly {
        mstore(0x0, pubKey)
        theo_adr := mload(0x0)
    }
    return is_this_a_pool == theo_adr;
}
```

In JS/ether:

```
const factory = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984'
const POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH = '0xe34f199b19b2b4f47f68442619d555527d244f78a3297ea89325f843f87b8b54'

const key = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode([ "address", "address", "uint24"], [token0, token1, fee]));
const keccack = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["bytes", "address", "bytes", "bytes32"], ["0xff", factory, key, POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH]);
console.log(ethers.utils.hexDataSlice(keccak, 12));

//keccak is 64 hex digit/nibbles == 32 bytes -> take rightmost 20 bytes=40 nibbles -> start at 64-40=24nibbles or 12 bytes
const theoretical_address = ethers.utils.hexDataSlice(keccak, 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";
```

In constructor initialize `token0,token1,pool`

```
constructor(
        address _factory,
        address _token0,
        address _token1,
        uint24 _fee
    ) {
        token0 = _token0;
        token1 = _token1;
        // https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments
        address _pool = IUniswapV3Factory(_factory).getPool(
            _token0,
            _token1,
            _fee
        );
        require(_pool != address(0), "Invalid pool");
        // if you are sure that _pool is a valid pool
        pool = _pool;
    }
```

when you get the `_pool` address by `IUniswapV3Factory`, if it exists it will return the pool address. `getPool` is a mapping. (since it is a public state variable, solidity assigns a getter so we can call it)

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => mapping(uint24 => address))) public override getPool;
```

if the address does not exist in the mapping, in other words, key does not exist. so `getPool(_token0,_token1,_fee);` will return default address value which is `address(0)`

Then with `require` statement check if the `_pool` address is `address(0)` or not

```
  require(_pool != address(0), "Invalid pool");
```

if `_pool` address is not `address(0)`, then you are sure that this a uniswap pool deployment