# Unit Testing UniswapV2Pair - function call to a non-contract account

Tags: solidity, uniswap, hardhat, unittesting

I'm trying to create unit tests for a token using Hardhat and run them locally.
The token uses Uniswap to swap for ETH.

Before each unit test, I...

1. Deploy `WETH`, `UniswapV2Factory`, and `UniswapV2Router02`.
2. Deploy my token

   - The token's constructor calls `uniswapFactory.createPair(this, weth)`

This all works properly and I'm able to run tests with my token.

However, one of my unit tests calls a function that ends up calling:

```
***Stack Trace***
UniswapV2Router02._swapSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens
UniswapV2Router02.swapExactTokensForEthSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens
```

https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L321

When it gets to line `329`, it errors out with `Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account`

Reference:
Create Pair code:
https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L23

---

I assume this means that the pair's address is not a contract that deployed locally.

**What else do I need to do in order to get my pair to be a working contract?**

I thought `createPair()` would be enough.

Comment: Have you tried console.log of the pair address (using Hardhat/console.sol)? Or, as an easiest alternative, have you considered forking mainnet and using the existing Uniswap deployment?

Comment: + add more precision in what you deployed, both UniswapV2Router01 and 02 ?

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth I have updated to mention I am using V2Router02.
I've also verified that when I first create the pair in my constructor, it does successfully call pair.initialize().

However, the pair address that gets created in my constructor (which uses `Factory.createPair()`) is different than the pair address that gets created from `swapExactTokensForEthSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` (which calls `UniswapLibrary.pairFor()`)

Comment: Pair address can be computed (that's what pairFor does iirc), to do so, you need the matching bytecode hash -> are you mixing "vanilla" uniswap and, for instance, pancakeswap ? Their bytecode is not identical, meaning pair addresses will not be the same

Comment: See this for V3, but the concept is the same : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/112709/68134 (I'd suggest again using a mainnet fork, which is really easier to work with)

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth Thanks. Yeah, you were right that the hash I was using in pairFor was not correct. Not sure why because I got the code directly from the github. But I was able to find the hash I needed by using `ethers.utils.keccak256(UniswapV2Pair.bytecode);`. If you want to add your comment as an answer, then I can mark it if you'd like.

Comment: Great, just added as an anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Factory.createPair()` will effectively deploy your pair contract, while when using UniswapLibrary.pairFor(), you will get the theoretical address of any potential pair, based on the uniswapV2Pair bytecode keccak256 hash (the "INIT_CODE" in get_pair()). If this hash differs than the one based on your actual deployment (ie an "old" value stayed hard-coded), createPair and pairFor will return different values.

See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/112709/68134 for similar concept in V3