# Restrict Uniswap Transactions to whitelisted Wallets

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, uniswap

Is there anyway at all to be able to have a contract that would restrict a wallet from being able to use Uniswap for a token until the contract owner has set a value to allow public access?

Every method that I've tried to put a restriction in place with seems to block it for any address I try with including the addresses that I have "WhiteListed".

Once I allow enough addresses to get the transaction to go through (token Contract, LP contract, UniswapRouter etc.) then all addresses seem to be able to get the transaction to go through??

Comment: Are you trying to create a new router-type contract for already existing tokens or do you plan to use this feature for the token that you are going to create?

Comment: @MaanasOT   -- This is for testing of a contract on the MainNet with real liquidity. So it's a feature of the token. But don't want people buying into a test Contract.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it's not a good idea. Uniswap is a decentralized and permissionless system, and is not designed to work with arbitrary restrictions. That said, Ethereum VM is a Turing complete computer, so of course you can force it to behave the way you want, somehow (subject to contract size limits and gas limits). Basically Uniswap needs to transfer your ERC20 tokens: to the pool if you're selling them; from the pool if you're buying them. So there can be some `if` statements and restrictions put in the `transfer` function of the ERC20 token contract.

1. At the periphery contract level, you set up could use transfer restrictions to and from various Uniswap Router contacts. It's not hard to do, the problem here is that it will not be a complete block, just an  anyone can write their own swap contract to interact with the pool, swap with the pool directly, or simply use another router like 1inch.
2. At the core contract level, you can exclude the pool itself from the transfers. Let's say that you're using TOKEN/ETH pool. If you know the address of TOKEN then it's possible to compute the TOKEN/ETH [address](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/guides/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses), even [off-chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710238/compute-uniswap-pair-address-via-python). You could first deploy the TOKEN proxy contract, note down it's address, compute TOKEN/ETH address, then change the TOKEN contract to exclude the TOKEN/ETH address from transfers, and deploy this new version onchain. The problem here is that anyone would still be able to swap using TOKEN/USDC, TOKEN/USDT, TOKEN/OTHER_TOKEN pools, so again, this is an inconvenience but not a complete solution.

**Edit:** the most reliable solution is probably check if the destination/source of a transfer is Uniswap pool by checking whether it has [a factory method](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/102600/77075) which returns `0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984`.

Comment: Thanks, I can block anyone from interacting with it at all by utilising a Trading Enabled Function. 
But then when I want to allow other certain wallets to be able to use it then I can use restrictions like a MaxTX size or MaxWallet size. And allow a list of wallets that bypass this limit or restriction and it works exactly as expected if trying to do token operations between wallets. 

The issue comes from the fact that those same restrictions seem to apply to all of the steps (addresses) along the way of the transaction via Uniswap? Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: @kfx In method 1, instead of excluding other contracts can't the user just allow his own router contract which could in turn check for the whitelisted user wallet addresses?

Comment: As @kfx stated you could and can put restrictions in the transfer function of the token contract. The problem arises when you are blocking all but the ones you have whitelisted. At this point it's evident that the blocks are then also applying to every other address including the routers, contracts, LP contracts etc.

Comment: I really have to wonder why people try to make these pointless restrictions on their tokens. What is the point?

Comment: Pointless to you perhaps. This is for testing of a contract on the MainNet with real liquidity. But don't want people buying into test Contract.